# Can anybody explain this strange variable expansion behaviour by cmd.exe with gzip?

Tags: gzip, cmd

I am running into the following problem with gzip.exe, be it from UnxUtils or from GnuWin32:

```
set gzip=.\util\gzip.exe
%gzip% test.txt
%gzip% test2.txt
```

The second gzip command will issue a warning like the following:

> gzip: .\util\gzip.exe.gz already exists; do you wish to overwrite (y or n)?

So: gzip tries to compress itself (and it still compresses test2.txt).
It is like if the command line was: `.\util.gzip.exe .\util.gzip.exe test2.txt`.

However, when in my batch my variable is not named gzip, then it works correctly.

```
set gzip_prg=.\util\gzip.exe
%gzip_prg% test.txt
%gzip_prg% test2.txt
```

I do not understand at all how the choice of a variable name can have an influence on the command line that is run after expansion.

In short, my batch script behaves in a different way ***when I change the name of a variable***!

Has anyone an explanation for this phenomenon?

Comment: Is it a problem having a variable `gzip` with the same name as the command? The message `gzip.exe.gz already exists` is very disturbing. You're not asking `gzip` to compress itself??

Comment: @pavium: edited question. gzip should not try to compress itself, however it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

[gzip.exe reads the `GZIP` environment variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/manual/gzip.html#Environment) that helps setting options.

Here, gzip reads the environment variable and considers therefore that it has to compress itself.